# I can modify an element in my char array , yet i cant modify another

Tags: java, arrays, char

I have a binary string and I am converting it to a char array 
for the purpose of modification. All I want to do is at a random generated index p, 
to look at that element and if it is a 0 make it a 1,and if a 1 make it a 0 .... 
it works for converting 1, but it doesnt work for converting the 0 to 1 !

```
    public class CS2004 
        {
            //Shared random object
            static private Random rand;
   //Create a uniformly distributed random integer between aa and bb inclusive
            static public int UI(int aa,int bb)
            {
            int a = Math.min(aa,bb);
            int b = Math.max(aa,bb);
            if (rand == null) 
            {
                rand = new Random();
                rand.setSeed(System.nanoTime());
            }
            int d = b - a + 1;
            int x = rand.nextInt(d) + a;
            return(x);
        }

    public class ScalesSolution
    {

    private String scasol;

    public void SmallChange(){

            int p;
            int n = scasol.length();
// converts the string into a char array so that we can access and modify it

            char [] y = scasol.toCharArray();

            // random integer p that ranges between 0 and n-1 inclusively
                    p = CS2004.UI(0,(n-1));
                    System.out.println(p);
        // we changing the element at index p from 0 to 1 , or from 1 to 0
        // cant convert from 0 to 1 !!!!! yet, it works for converting 1 to 0!  
                         if(y[p] == 0){
                y[p] = '1';

            } else {
                y[p] = '0';
            }

            // Now we can convert the char array back to a string 
            scasol = String.valueOf(y);
        }

        public void println()
        {
            System.out.println(scasol);
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

    public class Lab9 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            String s = "1100";

            ScalesSolution solution = new ScalesSolution(s);
            solution.println();

            // FLIPPING THE '1' BUT NOT FLIPPING THE '0'
            solution.SmallChange();
            solution.println(); 

        }

    }
```

Comment: Try putting single quotes on `if(y[p] == '0')`

Comment: thank you! it was silly of me to not see that!

Answer (score 3):

The integer value of the character '0' is not 0. It's 48. So the following test is incorrect:

```
if(y[p] == 0) {
```

It should be

```
if(y[p] == 48) {
```

or, much more readable:

```
if(y[p] == '0') {
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not compare characters like that!

```
if(y[p] == '0'){
```

Comment: This is not a moral issue. Chars are 2-bytes unsigned integer values, this is why `(ch == 0)` is legal code. It just means something different from `(ch == '0')`.

Answer (score 0):

In `Java`, `String` stores `Unicode characters`, in your case, the Unicode of character `'0'`is 48. So, you can either compare like this:

```
 if(y[p] == '0')
```

Or

```
 if(y[p] == 48)
```